# How to import javascript files from the same directory as a Rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

How can I precompile and import a javascript file, while keeping it in the same folder as the views its associated with?

For example, I'd like to keep `companies.js` inside the same `/view` directory as my other company views

**For example:**

```
/app/views/companies/_form.html.erb
/app/views/companies/index.html.erb
/app/views/companies/new.html.erb
/app/views/companies/edit.html.erb
/app/views/companies/companies.js <--- like this
```

This allows better organization than a large number of javascript files in `/app/assets/javascripts/`.

I've seen it done before, but I've been unable to replicate it now.

Using `<% javascript_include_tag 'companies' %>` tries to find the file in `/assets/javascripts/`.

Comment: Will You not have a problem with precompile assets in production when use this location for js?

Comment: I would agree, but I've seen it done in a Rails apps before

Answer (score 0):

Try change the manifest file in app/assets/config/manifest.js to compile .js in view's folders.

E.g

`//= link_directory ../javascripts .js`

add this with the path to your view folder

Comment: Can you give an example of what that might look like?

Comment: My answer was helpful?